# for 1 second: objective c coding help

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables, if-statement

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
if (myVariable == 100 for more than 1 second) {
}
```

So if myVariable equals 100 for more than 1 second do something.

Thanks!
Elijah

Comment: I would say it seems you take a wrong approach to solve a problem. What is the context of this code? Why do you want to do such a thing? Maybe we can figure out another approach.

Comment: Well I'm doing a speach recognition engine so that when you stop speaking (sound goes below a certain level) it sends the command in from a text field (pressing return). As a fail-safe (almost...) I only want to send the command when it's COMPLETELY sure that the speaker has stopped talking. ANy ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start an NSTimer from within the body of the if() statement that has a timer of 1 second. So something like

```
if(myVariable >= 100 && myTimer == nil){
    //NSTimer code here
}else if(myVariable < 100 && myTimer !=nil){
    //Invalidate timer
    //Set myTimer to nil
}
```

If you get the timer to call a method that then does what you want.

This should work but I can't help but feel there is a better solution to the actual problem your trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the time when you set myVariable to a new value (easy if you use a setter method for this all over the place). Then start a timer that fires after a second and check if you didn't change the value in meantime.

It's an unusual pattern though, and there are probably better ways to do what you try to accomplish.

Comment: What are some other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like that is not possible. Different approach probably could solve that. i.e. you can leave some kind of a timestamp every time when someone changes myVariable and then just see how much has passed since the last change.